# MongoDb c# driver need to compare datetime

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

The following code

```
var query = Query.And(
                  Query.EQ("p2l.listId", mailListId),
                  Query.LTE("p2l.subscriptionDate", dateTime.ToIsoDateTime())
                  );
return query;
```

Will give the following result

```
{  
   "p2l.listId":39974,
   "p2l.subscriptionDate":{  
      "$gte":"ISODate('2015-07-01 00:00:00')"
   }
}
```

`ToIsoDateTime` -is my custom extention method

How to prevent wrapping the ISODate with " ? Query will work fine without a double quotes.
The way with lambda-query is not convenient for me, how can i implement it ?

Comment: Why do you have `ToIsoDateTime`. Just use the dateTime itself.

Answer (score 1):

There is only need to use `dateTime` without extension method and it will work fine.